# Docker compose: can't access GPU from compose (but can from run)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia-docker

I've installed `nvidia-container-runtime` on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04), and can access the GPU through `docker run`.

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59 nvidia-smi
Mon Oct 24 00:32:32 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8    44W / 370W |     68MiB / 10240MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when running with the following `docker-compose.yml`, `nvidia-smi` can't be found. Applications inside the container don't seem to be using the GPU either.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nvidia:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    runtime: nvidia
    deploy:
        resources:
          reservations:
            devices:
              - capabilities: [gpu]
    command:
      ["nvidia-smi"]
```

Running `docker-compose up`

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container docker-compose-gpu-nvidia-1  Recreated                                                            0.0s
Attaching to docker-compose-gpu-nvidia-1
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "nvidia-smi": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

If I swap the selenium image to `nvidia/cuda`, `docker-compose` can see the GPU. Why is the GPU accessible in `docker run` but not `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the driver & count fixed this.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nvidia:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    runtime: nvidia
    deploy:
        resources:
          reservations:
            devices:
              - driver: nvidia
                count: 1
                capabilities: [gpu]
    command:
      ["nvidia-smi"]
```

I'm not sure why this worked - the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/) seem to indicate that omitting these will just use all available GPUs.